# Visual studio Browser Link not working with non local browser

Tags: visual-studio-2015, browser-link

I am trying to enable Browser Link update feature to update a few different browsers each time I press the shortcut. The update works OK for the browsers on the same machine as VS but not on the remote browsers.

The server (IIS express) is configured to serve remote clients and they Load the site as expected. However the JavaScript code required for the update is not included in the Html response.

I thought maybe the feature works with local connections only and tried to use a  port forward to achieve this without success. the Browsers on both machines are Chrome v48

Any Idea ?

Comment: I have spend a lot of time trying to make this work. Browser-Sync does this and a lot more and it took me 5 minutes to configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser Link is currently restricted to local browsers because of security concerns.

A Browser Link connection can be used to execute code inside Visual Studio. Since VS is often run as an elevated user, that can enable someone to execute code with elevated permissions using an unauthenticated HTTP connection.

Support for remote browsers may be added in the future, if we can come up with adequate security safeguards.